# want to implement Outlook REST API for WebAPI (stateless). to get all events and sync my app events in to Outlook calender

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-restapi

Platform : WebAPI (StateLess). there is no webpage/HTML page on my app.

1. Get all events
2. add events from My DB (my application database)

Comment: I'll appreciate quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at graph.microsoft.io at the events API - http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/calendar.  You can get events from graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events or graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview (for a specific timeframe).  You can create new events by POST to graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events.